# Keyboard language selection doesn't show with UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So i'm facing a weird behavior for my iOS app where the keyboard attached to some UITextFields does show the option to switch to another language whereas for other it doesn't as shown in the following pictures.

Image with language selection option:
[image]

Image without language selection option:
[image]

Even though they have the same code basically
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at [UIKeyboardType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype):

In your code : `self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;` change to `self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;`

or In Storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In my case** I had to set `Application language` tab inside `xcscheme` to **System Language** instead of **English**.

This is how it looks like:

first I opened `edit schemes`

[image]

and then i set `Application Language` to `System Language`:

[image]